# Update 2 Columns in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I want to update to columns when a particular condition satisfies.

For example:

We will first load data

```
A = load 'students.txt' as (name:chararray, age:int, gpa:float);
```

Now,

```
B = foreach A generate name, (age==18?1:age) as age, gpa;
```

Here whenever my condition for age is satisfied at the same instant I want to update one more column say is_adult and set it's value to true and this column in created dynamically(As you observe is_adult column is not there in original schema).

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = LOAD 'students.txt' AS (name:chararray, age:int, gpa:float);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE
    name,
    (age==18?1:age) AS age,
    (age>=18?'true':'false') AS adult,
    gpa ;
```

The `adult` column would be updated with `true` or `false` based on the value of `age`. This is a pretty standard way of doing this. The new schema/alias obtained in the `FOREACH` loop can have more (or less) number of columns than the original alias.